# Node.js v5.1.0 'arguments' not allowing me to access nested array properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments

I've got a class that I'm instantiating in two different ways:

```
_client.setAppAuth(clientId, clientSecret, tokenTtl)
_client.setAppAuth({
    clientId: clientId,
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
    tokenTtl: tokenTtl
})
```

I've got a setter/getter defined, and a helper method:

```
Object.defineProperty(MyClient.prototype, "appAuth", {
    get: function() {
        return appAuth
    },
    set: function(opts) {
        console.log(arguments)
    }
})

MyClient.prototype.setAppAuth = function(opts) {
    this.appAuth = typeof opts === 'object' ? opts : arguments
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the arguments from this instantiation using [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

In the `console.log()`, I get the following:

```
{ '0': 
   { '0': 'YXA6GXSAACS2EeOYd20aP4G6Lw',
     '1': 'YXA66BeEvgNpJBwc4PAbvZZGTVS_SSw',
     '2': 3600 } }

{ '0': 
   { clientId: 'YXA6GXSAACS2EeOYd20aP4G6Lw',
     clientSecret: 'YXA66BeEvgNpJBwc4PAbvZZGTVS_SSw',
     tokenTtl: 3600 } }
```

That looks about right for what I'm expecting. Here's the weird part though:

```
console.log(arguments[0])
```

gets me this:

```
{ '0': 'YXA6GXSAACS2EeOYd20aP4G6Lw',
  '1': 'YXA66BeEvgNpJBwc4PAbvZZGTVS_SSw',
  '2': 3600 }
{ clientId: 'YXA6GXSAACS2EeOYd20aP4G6Lw',
  clientSecret: 'YXA66BeEvgNpJBwc4PAbvZZGTVS_SSw',
  tokenTtl: 3600 }
```

But when I do:

```
console.log(arguments[0][0]) // or arguments[0]["0"]
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

I realize that `arguments` isn't actually an Array (it has a length property though) shouldn't I still be able to access the inner property values like it were an object? `typeof arguments[0]` returns `object`? What gives? Is this a Node implementation bug, or am I just not doing it right? How can I get the object values out of `arguments[0]`?

---

**Update**

Doing a try/catch like so:

```
try {
    console.log(opts, Object.keys(opts))
} catch (e) {

}
```

logs out:

```
{ '0': 'YXA6GXSAACS2EeOYd20aP4G6Lw',
  '1': 'YXA66BeEvgNpJBwc4PAbvZZGTVS_SSw',
  '2': 3600 } [ '0', '1', '2' ]
{ clientId: 'YXA6GXSAACS2EeOYd20aP4G6Lw',
  clientSecret: 'YXA66BeEvgNpJBwc4PAbvZZGTVS_SSw',
  tokenTtl: 3600 } [ 'clientId', 'clientSecret', 'tokenTtl' ]
```

So clearly it appears that somewhere it's trying to execute the setter function by passing a null argument? But when logging `console.log(e)` or `e.stack`, there's no output. The `catch` block is never even reached? Clearly something else is going on here - going to strip the entire lib out and try to reproduce with an SSCCE.

Comment: You're using `arguments` twice, which makes no sense. In the setter, you should only use `opts`, as there is ever only a single argument.

Comment: Inside the setter, you've got `opts === arguments[0]`. This is the value that you passed in from `setAppAuth`, i.e. `=== typeof opts === 'object' ? opts : arguments`. And it has either `.clientId` (etc) properties (when it's the `obj`) or it has indices (when it's the `arguments`).

Comment: Oh wait, I see your problem now. Do you get the error as well when you try `obj[0]` instead of `arguments[0][0]`?

Comment: "*`typeof arguments[0]` returns `object`? What gives?*" - yes, `typeof null == "object"` (for some weird historic reasons). Regardless, you're not doing `_client.setAppAuth(null)` anywhere, do you? Or is `clientId` null sometimes?

Comment: So did some checking, and I think you meant `opts[0]` not `obj[0]`. Same error when using `opts[0]`. No, `clientId` is never null - and when I log out plain `opts`, I get a payload identical to the final console.log statement (identical to `arguments[0]`). Here's a further thickening of the plot: logging `Object.keys(opts)` gets me `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`...

Comment:  it works in my SSCCE. So something else in what I've written is clobbering it. At least I know... now I just have to figure out wtf.